# What is the difference between these two ways to leverage the arguments object in a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

In the documentation for the `Array.prototype.slice` method it says:

> Binding can be done with the .call function of Function.prototype and
>   it can also be reduced using [].slice.call(arguments) instead of
>   Array.prototype.slice.call.

```
function getArgs() {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
  return args;
}
getArgs(1,2,3); // returns [1, 2, 3]

function getArgs2() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  return args;
}
getArgs2(1,2,3); // returns [1, 2, 3]
```

Essentially what is the difference? Is there a performance benefit using one over the other method? Or is the former just easier to type out?

Comment: a rose by another name: `[].slice==Array.prototype.slice`

Answer (score 2):

Those both do the same thing, which is to call the array `.slice()` method. The first way gets at the function via the implicit prototype lookup from a new empty array, and the other goes explicitly to the `Array.prototype` object. There is probably a performance difference but it's not significant or relevant, since both ways throw away a lot of performance anyway: passing the `arguments` object out of a function is likely to make the runtime system give up on optimizing the function.

To avoid that performance penalty, a simple local `for` loop should be used instead:

```
function foo() {
  var args = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) args[i] = arguments[i];
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Even if the function were not returning the `arguments` back to the caller, doing `[].slice()` is worse than invoking `Array.prototype.slice()` directly because the empty array way has to allocate memory and then that allocated memory will be discarded right away. So `Array.prototype` is always a wiser choice

Comment: @Dummy that's probably true, but the actual difference is trivial, and there's no reason to believe that a modern runtime wouldn't optimize the object creation out anyway (because the array object is never subsequently referenced).  The performance sacrifice made by passing `arguments` to another function is vastly more important.